# Regular expression find numbers anywhere in a string (assert no numbers in a string)

Tags: regex

I am trying to build a regular expression that will **disallow** one or more of any digits 0 to 9 anywhere in a string as part of a validation routine.  The string is allowed to have letters, letters with accents, punctuation, spaces etc

Edited by suggestion: a better statement of my requirements is to assert no numbers in a string.

I am given by way of an example `regexp=^[A-Za-z]{1,20}$`to **allow** up to 20 alphabetic characters

I have tried `[^0123456789]` this disallows numbers but not if there are also letters or spaces or punctuation.

Using Javascript

I would be most obliged for any assistance with this. Thanks

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Shouldn't the title be `assert no numbers in a string` then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to disallow digits in the string:

```
^[^0-9]*$
```

The regex works as follows: `[0-9]` is a list of all digits. By placing the circumflex in the group, you obtain the negation (thus any character exception the digits).

By adding the star, you say it can match any number of non-digits.

Now we only need to force that the regex spans the entire string. This is done by placing a circumflex in the front and a dollar at the end.

Comment: Thanks, should I use the g and m options?

Comment: not `g` stands for global, but since we match the entire string, perhaps `m` is useful.

Answer (score 3):

There is a special [shorthand character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\D` that only matches characters that aren't digits. Therefore, you can use

```
^\D*$
```

to make sure your string doesn't contain any digits.

```
/^\D*$/.test(subject)
```

will return `True` if `subject` does not contain any (ASCII) digits.

Comment: Tim, This did not work for me, does this shorthand character class work in Javascrip?  I will experiment over the weekend.

Comment: Thanks, I will make a simpler test case to try to establish why this is not working for me.

Answer (score 3):

You could try this,

```
^[^0-9]{1,20}$
```

Not character class is used here, which allows all the characters except digits. The char length must be form 1 to 20(ie, upto 20 characters).

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/bY3lL5/3)

Comment: Great to get the reference to the regex test site for the demo.  I did not accept your answer as the maximum number up to 20 is a restriction that I might forget about.